# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: ResizeObserver on browsers that support ResizeObserver (Safari v15.6.1)

Tags: mobile-safari, polyfills, resize-observer

I'm seeing users get the error `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: ResizeObserver` even though the browser they are on (Safari v15.6.1, v16.1) are versions that are supposed to support ResizeObserver.

Anyone have an idea what could be causing this?

P.S. - I'm also using polyfill.io to load in a ResizeObserver polyfill for browsers that don't support it, but I guess it's not downloading a polyfill in these cases since these browsers versions supposedly support ResizeObserver

Thanks